# Computing time in and time out in PHP

Tags: php

How can I compute the difference between time in PHP?

Example:

time in is -> 08:00:00 AM

andtime out is -> 05:00:00 PM

times are set as a variables.
how can I compute it with PHP?
Im getting confused with that AM and PM.

Comment: time in and time out of what?

Comment: oh sorry, im currently developing a payroll system right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for only count the difference between time(in hour), then you can try it as:

```
$seconds = strtotime('08:00:00 AM') - strtotime('05:00:00 PM');
echo $hours = abs(floor($seconds/3600));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
 $time1=strtotime('08:00:00 AM');
 $time2= strtotime('05:00:00 PM');
 $diff = $time2 - $time1;
 echo  date('H:i:s', $diff)
?>
```

**Output**

```
 09:00:00
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/182867)

Comment: Just keep in mind that this code will give you perfect output only if the difference between times is less than 24 hour, after that you will need to create a logic calculating the day also

Comment: I have added info for his knowledge and not against you bro :)

Comment: @Veerendra, I am just telling about his requirment